# Send the message objc_msgSend(class,@selector(dealloc)) to release the object, why is it wrong to access the object pointer?

Tags: objective-c, msgsend

The code is under ARC. When I delete the code `NSObject* objc = (NSObject*)object;` the program runs fine, but I didn't have access to the pointer `objc`. When I keep the code `NSObject* objc = (NSObject*)object;` I am prompted `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)`. Is the system accessing the `objc` pointer after the block function body ends?

```
-(void)resetDeallocMethodWithInstance:(NSObject*)obj
{
    Class targetClass = obj.class;
    @synchronized (swizzledClasses()) {
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(obj.class);
        if ([swizzledClasses() containsObject:className]) return;
        SEL deallocSel = sel_registerName("dealloc");
        __block void (*deallocBlock)(__unsafe_unretained id, SEL) = NULL;
        id block = ^(__unsafe_unretained id object){
            NSObject* objc = (NSObject*)object;
            NSUInteger hash = ((NSObject*)object).hash;
            [self removeAllTargetWitSuffixKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)hash]];
            if (deallocBlock == NULL) {
                struct objc_super superInfo = {
                    .receiver = object,
                    .super_class = class_getSuperclass(targetClass)
                };
                void (*msgSend)(struct objc_super *, SEL) = (__typeof__(msgSend))objc_msgSendSuper;
                msgSend(&superInfo, deallocSel);
            } else {
                deallocBlock(object, deallocSel);
            }
        };
        IMP blockImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(block);
        if (!class_addMethod(obj.class, deallocSel, blockImp, "v@:")) {
            Method deallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(obj.class, deallocSel);
            deallocBlock = (__typeof__(deallocBlock))method_getImplementation(deallocMethod);
            deallocBlock = (__typeof__(deallocBlock))method_setImplementation(deallocMethod, blockImp);
        }
        [swizzledClasses() addObject:className];
    }
    return;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEgIc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This answer is being directly typed in, your code has **not** been tested, indeed **no** code has been tested. Therefore that the issues below are causing your issues is being inferred.*

There area number of issues with your design:

- Swizzling `dealloc` is not recommended. The `dealloc` method is called automatically by the system when it is in the process of destroying an object, as such using the partly destroyed object inappropriately (whatever that might be) could lead to issues - as you have found!
- You are using ARC under which ["an implementation of dealloc, [should] not invoke the superclass’s implementation"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571947-dealloc). However your block does this.
- The variable `objc` is unused. However by default a local variable has the attribute `strong` so you are creating a strong reference to an object in the process of destruction. Any strong reference made by the block in this way will be released by ARC when the block has finished, this is almost certainly not good as your error indicates.

You appear to be trying to call your `removeAllTargetWithSuffixKey:` method when a particular object is destroyed (*appear* as you swizzle [and can only swizzle] the *class* but are using the `hash` of a particular object). A better way to do this avoiding swizzling is to use *associated objects*.

The runtime function [`objc_setassociatedobject()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418509-objc_setassociatedobject?language=objc) allows you to attach an object to a particular instance of another object and have that object be destroyed automatically when its host is destroyed (use an `objc_AssociationPolicy` of `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN`).

Design a class which has an instance property of your required `hash` value and a `dealloc` method which calls your `removeAllTargetWithSuffixKey:` then rather than swizzle the class simply create and associate an instance of your class with the target object.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's accessing the pointer after the method ends.  If this is being compiled under ARC, then the objc is a "strong" reference.  However, you are fabricating the implementation of the *dealloc* method, and so are retaining the object when it's already going to be dealloced, so it's too late to have a strong reference to it.  Your implementation is going to call super, which should actually deallocate the object, and then afterwards ARC is going to release the objc value, but it's already gone since it's the receiver, i.e. "self" if you were writing a normal dealloc method.

ARC will never retain self in a regular dealloc method, but that is what you are effectively doing.  The "object" value is the same pointer, but is explicitly __unsafe_unretained, so you should just use that directly.  You can type the block as NSObject* instead of id if that helps, but it shouldn't matter.  Or you can make your objc value also __unsafe_unretained so ARC leaves it alone.  You don't want ARC touching the "self" value inside the block in any way, since you are going around ARC's back in this case.

Whatever the case, once you are in an object's dealloc method, don't ever retain/release/autorelease the self pointer -- it will end up with crashes.  Calling a method from dealloc and passing a reference to self is a no-no, for example.  You need to be very careful about that, and understand exactly what ARC is doing if you are playing these types of runtime games.